# Aligning Liniar layout children

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical LiniarLayout with wrap content width.
I want to make all the children same width (width of the biggest children) not using fixed dimens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Short"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Short"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some long text to match layout"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="short"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more explicit in your question? When you say children, what kinds of views are? 
if you want all children to have the same size, just that you use - width="match_parent" - in childrens. 
That answer your question? 
This is a example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Worldddd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Worldddddddddddddddddddddddd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Worldddd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Worldddddddddddd" />

    </LinearLayout>
```